# Making a mistake with | (or) in regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm sure I'm doing something really obviously wrong here, but I can't figure out what. Using grep from a bash shell, I have a file test.txt:

```
ABC123
ABC456
ABC789
DEF123
DEF456
DEF789
```

Now at the command line:

```
$ grep ABC test2.txt
ABC123
ABC456
ABC789

$ grep DEF test2.txt
DEF123
DEF456
DEF789
```

So those work great. Now, I expect the following command to print the whole file, but:

```
$ grep ABC\|DEF test2.txt

$ grep (ABC)\|(DEF) test2.txt
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `ABC'

$ grep \(ABC\)\|\(DEF\) test2.txt

$ grep 'ABC|DEF' test2.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn on the extended regex with -E:

```
grep -E "ABC|DEF" test2.txt
```

Comment: This fixed it! This site was not clear about regular vs extended regex... http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, standard `grep` command does not support the *or* syntax. Unfortunately, from there, things are a mishmash.

- Some systems have a `egrep` that does offer *or* syntax.
- Some systems can use a `-E` or `-P` (for Perl) flag to extend grep syntax.
- Some systems have both the `-E` and `egrep` that do the same thing. This implies that there are systems out there where `grep -E` and `egrep` are not the same. (sad but true).
- Some systems now use the extended regular expressions in their standard `grep` command. Apparently, your system doesn't.

Read your manpages to see what your system does support. Some systems have a manpage for `re_format`that will explain what they support and don't support in extended format.

Then again, you could always just use a Perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -ne "print if /(ABC)|(DEF)/" test.txt
```

At least you know all the stuff that supports.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think standard syntax supports it. You could use `-P` switch if available:

```
grep -P "(ABC|DEF)" test2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`egrep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?egrep) instead, which is the same as using `grep -E`:

```
egrep 'ABC|DEF' test2.txt
```